# Extract numeric part of string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to clean up a database containing strings like this:

```
<a href="/members/a/" title="a">a</a> ist der Gruppe <a href="/groups/3106/">a</a> beigetreten
```

or also

```
<a href="/members/a/" title="a">a</a> ist der Gruppe <a href="/groups/3106_123/">a</a> beigetreten
```

or also

```
<a href="/members/a/" title="a">a</a> ist der Gruppe <a href="/groups/3106_A/">a</a> beigetreten
```

or also

```
<a href="/members/a/" title="a">a</a> ist der Gruppe <a href="/groups/3106A/">a</a> beigetreten
```

I only need the numeric part after `/groups/`, so in this examples, only "3106". The number is of variable length.

Stripping the first part away is easy:

```
SUBSTRING(field, locate('groups/', field)+7)
```

but how to strip the rest away?

Comment: I think you might have to do a little bit in code, a regex would help you find what you need in MySQL but you can't extract from it.

Comment: I would use a scripting language for this.

Comment: Thanks guys. I would also appreciate an answer with a PHP-regex so I could write a small program with that.

Comment: Here you are: `(?<=\/groups\/)[0-9]+`. See https://regex101.com/r/zG8pL9/1

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking for a [PHP regex](https://regex101.com/r/zG8pL9/1), here you are:

```
(?<=\/groups\/)[0-9]+
```

PHP sample code:

```
$re = "/(?<=\\/groups\\/)[0-9]+/"; 
$str = "<a href=\"/members/a/\" title=\"a\">a</a> ist der Gruppe <a href=\"/groups/3106A/\">a</a> beigetreten"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way using `REGEX` of `MYSQL` to select only numeric of your string column value

```
SELECT column_name_of_db
FROM db_name
WHERE column_name_of_db REGEXP '^(?<=\/groups\/)\d+';
```

[image]